# wp вывод статей на статической странице

Tags: php, wordpress, ооп

Есть код вывода статей на статической странице с постраничной навигацией:

```
<article>

    <?php // Display blog posts on any page @ http://m0n.co/l
    $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('showposts=5' . '&paged='.$paged);
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Read more"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php if ($paged > 1) { ?>

    <nav id="nav-posts">
        <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Posts'); ?></div>
        <div class="next"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts &raquo;'); ?></div>
    </nav>

    <?php } else { ?>

    <nav id="nav-posts">
        <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Posts'); ?></div>
    </nav>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</article>
```

https://wpcafe.org/tutorials/otobrazhenie-zapisey-bloga-na-lyuboy-stranitse-s-navigatsiey/

Вот сама страница с кодом.

Все работает, только нужно добавить условие: загружать посты только из категории `news`.

Comment: Вставьте код текстом в тело вопроса, так требуют правила сообщества. Код должен индексироваться поисковиками.

Comment: исправил заменил на код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять строчку

```
$wp_query->query('showposts=5' . '&paged='.$paged);
```

на

```
$wp_query->query('category_name=news&showposts=5' . '&paged='.$paged);
```

Comment: спасибо is work)